# Ignoring (but still working with) Non-conforming Lines in CSV for Updating Data

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have been looking into parsing data from URL's with the end goal of having live or updating data visuals. The current one I'm working on is from a google finance URL. The API is no longer with us (may it rest in peace), the following is just some backfill data -- which is still functional. I'm not trying to do production-quality code or anything; it's more like proof of concept for me.

```
EXCHANGE%3DINDEXSP
MARKET_OPEN_MINUTE=570
MARKET_CLOSE_MINUTE=960
INTERVAL=300
COLUMNS=DATE,OPEN
DATA=
TIMEZONE_OFFSET=-240
a1521120900,555.45
1,554.53
2,554.07
3,553.9
4,552.67
...
```

The trouble is, while the data looks to follow at comma separated value format (i.e. the last 4 rows in the above example), the first 7 lines don't conform. There also appears to be no header. Some of the information in the first few lines will be useful for converting the unix time to a date object, but I could probably do a separate function for that. Like a deer in the headlights, I didn't know what to do, so I just parsed it as a csv to see what would happen. Here is what `d3.csv()` looked like in the console:

```
Array(84)
    0:object
        EXCHANGE%3DINDEXSP: "MARKET_OPEN_MINUTE=570"
...
    8:object
        EXCHANGE%3DINDEXSP: "2"
...
```

So it seems that it treats `EXCHANGE%3DINDEXSP` as a header and uses it all the way through. That's understandable, I didn't give it an easy format to work with. It's at this point I'm not sure how to proceed.

**Question:** How do I have my `csv` parser ignore the first few lines and read the data in the absence of a header? I will also still need to be able to accept updates to the data (which will be in the original format as per the top of the post).

I suppose I could add a header after the fact, I'm not sure how I'd do that though either. The correct headers should be `interval,open`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially use `d3.text` instead of `d3.csv`:

```
d3.text('data.csv', function(error, rawData) {

  var data =
    rawData
      .split("\n")
      .slice(7)
      .map(r => {
        var split = r.split(",");
        var l = new Object();
        l.k = split[0];
        l.v =  split[1];
        return l;
      });

  console.log(data);
});
```

Which produces:

```
[
  {k: "a1521120900", v: "555.45"},
  {k: "1", v: "554.53"},
  {k: "2", v: "554.07"},
  {k: "3", v: "553.9"},
  {k: "4", v: "552.67"}
]
```

---

- `rawData` is a string representing the content of the file.
- We split `rawData` to get an array of lines.
- We then drop the first 7 lines: `.slice(7)`.
- And each line is then split and transformed into an object.

Comment: Yeah, that's a great solution for sure. The `new Object()` is probably the best so I can still work with the unstructured rawData.